# Finding nearest line from points in SpatiaLite?

Tags: spatialite, proximity, knn

I have writtern a query in Spatialite to get the nearest line from a point. I want to do that for all points. How can I modify the below codes:

```
SELECT g1.id As gref_id, g2.id As gnn_gid

FROM CLP_substations As g1, ib5000_contours As g2  

where g1.id = 1 and g1.id <> g2.id

ORDER BY ST_Distance(g1.geom,g2.geom) 

limit 1
```

Comment: delete the where and make limit as the total row number of g1 seems to work. But it is very very slow for 14832 rows. Any suggestions?

Comment: what SpatiaLite version are you using?

Comment: st_distance is a postgis-function.  Are you using postgis or spatialite? https://www.gaia-gis.it/spatialite-2.0/spatialite2_sql.html

Comment: @PieterB it exists in newer versions http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
SELECT  a.id,
        b.id,
        MIN(ST_Distance(a.geometry, b.geometry)) AS dist
FROM    <points> AS a,
        <lines> AS b
GROUP BY
        a.id
;
```

but note that this will be equally inefficient. There is currently no table function support within SQLite, so concepts like the `LATERAL` join are not available. This also means there can be no index enhanced *(K)NN* search.

---

With *SpatiaLite* 4.4.0-RC0 and above (5.0.0 is in active development) there seems to be KNN support via *[VirtualKNN](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=KNN)* tables. AFAIK, currently you'll have to compile both versions yourself, as both haven't been released.

Comment: I find it a bit confusing to follow the *SpatiaLite* release management; feel free to correct me if the version considerations are not correct.

Comment: There are 5.0-beta Windows binaries available from https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/index.html through the "next generation" links.